# Dual SIM: is it possible to have two Android user accounts each using one SIM

Tags: accounts, dual-sim

I am planning to purchase a dual-SIM Android smartphone to use it with two user accounts, completely separated. To clarify: user account One would receive all calls, SMS etc. to SIM card 1 and user account Two would receive all calls, SMS etc. to SIM card 2. Each account should have full rights to make calls, install apps etc. within their account. I just want to switch the users, not manually switch the SIM card used after every account switch.

Is this possible with Android currently?

Comment: SIMs cannot be tied to users... And even though there are different users possible in some Android devices, they still have many shared resources which can vary by Android version and OEM implementation.

Comment: This is a very special use case and is not covered by the common way how devices usually work as acejavelin already pointed out. However Android is an open system and a lot of vendors heavily modify it. Therefore you never know - may be one device exists on the marked that would allow Android the way you want. But I never heard something like that.